# Mips programming, How to call a function from a separate file

Tags: mips

I have a relatively basic question, I've been having trouble calling a function from a separate file. My googling has come up short, there is a lot for the other languages but not much in the way of MIPS.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

MIPS isn't a language, it is an instruction set architecture.

Assuming you really mean that you are programming in MIPS assembler AND you are using the GCC toolchain including GNU assembler, you need to declare your function with a `.global myfunc` in the file where it is implemented, then the linker should be able to resolve the function name where it is used in another file e.g. `jal myfunc`.

You don't need to use an `.extern myfunc` directive in the file where `myfunc` is used because the GNU tools treat all undefined symbols as external.

If you are using MARS, then none of this applies.